# Routing Error in Rails 3.2

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting a routing error in

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}
```

running `rake routes` gives me the following:

```
   edit_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)          projects#edit
        user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)               projects#show
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)               projects#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)               projects#destroy
```

and the error is coming from `projects/new`.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You might have a link_to call to `edit_project_path` when you should use the nested `edit_user_project_path` route.

Comment: Sidenote: The [Better Errors](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel) gem will display the exact source code around the lines that raise the exception, so you'll find it more easily. It's worth including in every Rails project. Would help a lot with this specific error by showing you the exact link_to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas Klemm - You got the right answer.  Posted here in case anyone else comes looking for a similar error.

NOTE:  `edit_user_project_path` (or similar) takes 2 arguments, in this case `@user` and `@project`.